# Asp.NET cookies returning null

Tags: asp.net, cookies

I'm trying to save a cookie when a button is clicked like so...

```
protected void btn_login_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("test");
   cookie["work"] = "now";
   cookie.Expires = DateTime.Now + new TimeSpan(1, 0, 0, 0);
   cookie.Domain = ".cookie.com";
   Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);
}
```

Then on the page_load I am reading the cookie...

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string a = Response.Cookies["test"]["work"];
}
```

But it keeps coming back null. I am running this under localhost and I read that cookies won't save under localhost so I edited my host file to say 
127.0.0.1        test.cookie.com
When I used Fiddler to see what was getting posted to the header of the page. It looks like this...

test/work = now
test =

So I can see that it is getting set but for some reason when I read it in it returns null.

Comment: Are you visiting `test.cookie.com` in your web browser? Or still localhost?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On the page_load change it from `Response.Cookies` to `Request.Cookies`.

The Response object is for sending data back.  The Request object has data that is passed to you.

example:

```
String a = Request.Cookies["test"]["work"];
```

Note that if the cookie doesn't exist, then this will cause a null reference exception.

Usually you should do something like:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  HttpCookie cookie = Request.Cookies["test"];
  String a = String.Empty;

  if (cookie != null) {
    a = cookie["work"];
  }

}
```

Comment: That's so obvious, I can't believe I didn't notice I was using Response to read a cookie. Sometimes it just takes someone else to look at it to see these easy mistakes. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 5):

Try this

```
Response.Cookies["work"].Value = "Value1"
```

Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178194.aspx) for more information.

On pageload for reading the cookie try

```
string value = Request.Cookies["work"].Value
```

Comment: @Rickyman35 - This is a valid answer. Praneeth did not deserve down vote.